# Today Stock Price is 15. Find value of Call Option

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, expected-value, trees

Stock price is $15$ today. In a year, it has $50-50$ chances of going up or down. If it goes up, then $0.8$ probability of the price being $25$. If it goes down, then $0.4$ probability of price being $5$ and $0.6$ probability of it being $0$. Find the price of $call$ $option$ at strike $25$.

---

My approach:

I think I should, first of all, find the value of the stock on the up branch of the tree that happens with a probability of 0.2. I don't know though how to find such value.

I thought to include in the reasoning the formulas of $p,u,d$ of the tree, but it doesn't seem to help.

[image: Tree]

This is the tree I am talking about. Nevertheless, in this problem, the tree should have only one node so $n=1$,  and since the maturity is 1 year, t should also be 1, $t=1$

Comment: How can you use a binomial model when there is a non-zero probability of attaining the value $0$?  For any $n$, $0 = S_0 \cdot d^n \implies d = 0$.

Comment: I guess these probabilities you are quoting are assumed to be risk-neutral and you're valuing under the assumption that there is a risk-neutral distribution? Otherwise the missing information of what happens the other 20% of the time it goes up is conspicuous. (And if so, that's a hint... what does the price need to be in that case for the distribution to be risk-neutral, assuming 0 interest rate, presumably?)

Comment: Are you implying that it should be 50? in that case, no. It should be 35, but how? I think yes, those are risk-neutral probabilities. @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: I get 40, actually (assuming 0 interest rates)... .3*0+.2*5+.4*25 + .1*40=15. What's the reasoning for 35?